# Linux Live USB's will not boot on MSI GT70-2OC

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, msi

I recently got a new laptop for Christmas, I love it. There is one crucial error though. It runs Windows 8. I cannot stand Windows, let alone Windows 8. I want to keep Windows 8 for the simple fact that this is a gaming PC, and sadly Linux is in the shallow end of the dream pool in that department. I cannot get the Ubuntu live USB to boot. In fact I cant get any Linux USB's to boot. I have tried every suggestion I have seen, other than updating the UFCI BIOS. That scares me. I have tried going into legacy mode, changing the way the SSD works, turning off fast boot, turning off secure boot, and  I even turned off the MSI boot logo. Nothing worked. I can boot into the USB but when I select Try Ubuntu without installing, it goes to a black screen and that's it. Any help would be appreciated.

Specs:
16 GB of RAM
750 GB SSD
Intel core i7
Nvidia GeForce GTX 770M

If you need any other info feel free to ask.